# How do I find the average of the result of a group by SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

So assuming I'm starting with a table called Inventory like the following where there are multiple unique items per non unique storage ID:

| ItemID | StorageID |
| --- | --- |
| 453 | 100 |
| 234 | 100 |
| 642 | 150 |
| 234 | 200 |
| 343 | 200 |
| 143 | 200 |

I group the items based on its storage ID so it would result in the following table - (`select itemID, storageID from Inventory group by storageID`)

| ItemID | StorageID |
| --- | --- |
| 453, 234 | 100 |
| 642 | 150 |
| 234, 343, 143 | 200 |

But then here is the part I'm stuck on: I want to return a single numerical result representing the average number of items per storage. So that would involve counting the number of items per each distinct storage (ie: storageID 100 has 2 items, storageID 200 has 3 items) and then finding an average. So in the example I shared, the average would be (2+1+3)/3 = 2.67 items/storage.
How could I query MySQL for this? Do I even need to use group by as a start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a subquery:

```
select count(*) / count(distinct storageID) as avg_per_storageID
from Inventory ;
```

The average is the total number of items divided by the number of `storageID`s.

Answer (score 2):

Group your data and use `count()` on each group.

```
select avg(cnt)
from
(
  select count(*) as cnt, storageID 
  from Inventory 
  group by storageID
) tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` as follows:

```
select avg(cnt) as average_
(select count(*) as cnt
  from your_table t
 group by storageid) t
```